# Sorting pairs of approximate numbers

Tags: sorting

In an ideal world I would have:

```
list1 = {{2, 0}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, -1}};
Sort[list1]
```

> {{2, -1}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}}

while in the real world I have:

```
list2 = {{1.999999927261, 2.33473182872375 10^-8},
         {2.00000002055154, -0.99999987168595},
         {2.00000013088255, -4.79449275287154 10^-8},
         {2.00000013921051, -1.00000012791526}};
Sort[list2]
```

> {{2., 2.33473 10^-8}, {2., -1.}, {2., -4.79449 10^-8}, {2., -1.}}

So, the question is: how to get the first sort with the second list?

> {{2., -1.}, {2., -1.}, {2., -4.79449 10^-8}, {2., 2.33473 10^-8}}

One idea would be to consider the integer part of such numbers, but does that make sense as what? Otherwise, what would you suggest? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one option could be

```
list2 = {{1.999999927261, 
   2.33473182872375 10^-8}, {2.00000002055154,-0.99999987168595}, 
{2.00000013088255, -4.79449275287154 10^-8}, {2.00000013921051, 
-1.00000012791526}}

Sort[list2, (#1[[1]] <= #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] <= #2[[2]]) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively

```
SortBy[list2, Last]
(*{{2., -1.}, {2., -1.}, {2., -4.79449*10^-8}, {2.,2.33473*10^-8}}*)
```

Comment: +1 If there are multiple clusters, broaden this to `Flatten[SortBy[#, Last] & /@ GatherBy[list2, Round[#[[1]]] &], 1]`